# Using Xcode 3.2, which performance tool to see how much memory my iPhone app is using?

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory-management

Also, is running an app in the simulator sufficient to get a ball park estimate or will I get very different values from running on the device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default (and a very good) tool is Instruments, which comes with the SDK.  Here is [Apple's doc on Instruments](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Memory usage on the simulator is generally the same, although if you are using OpenGL ES, the simulator has significantly less memory errors (and better performance) on the simulator.  So the general rule of thumb is: it's ok to test your memory on the simulator, except for OpenGL ES usage.

Answer (score 1):

When you run the application using Instruments (Object Allocations) in the simulator, that should give you a very accurate memory usage picture.